# Join tables from different databases, servers in SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have one table called "EEmailSentdata" which belongs to database "A" and another table "EEventGuest" which belongs to database "B", I want to make a query by joining these tables, is it possible?

Comment: Using LINQ will be very expensive if the two tables are big and need to be pulled into the app first before making the join.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If both database are on the same SQL Server it is pretty simple. You just prefix the table names with the database name and the name of the schema. If they are not on the same SQL instance you will have to create a connected server object and prefix the table with that objects name. Thats it

Create a linked server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ff772782.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If they are on same server, and depends which JOIN you need:

```
SELECT * FROM A.EEmailSentdata a
(CROSS/LEFT/INNER) JOIN B.EEventGuest b ON a.ID = b.ID
```